# Find the number of 5 digit numbers divisible by $4$ which can be formed by using $0,1,2,3,4,5$ when the repetition of digits is allowed

Tags: combinatorics

I know that a number is divisible by $4$ if its last two digits are divisible by $4$
From the given numbers $6$ 2 digit numbers can be formed that are divisible by $4$ ($00$,$44$,$24$,$04$,$40$,$20$)
For each 2 digit combination there can be $5$ * $6$ * $6$

5 digit numbers

So the answer should be $5$ * $6$ * $6$ * $6$= $1080$

But the answer is given as $1620$

Comment: You're missing some two-digit numbers divisible by $4$.

Comment: which ones?
there definitely can't be any 2 digit number divisible by 4 made with 1,3 & 5
so that leaves 0,2,4 from which there are 9 possible 2 digit numbers divisible by 4 out of which 02,22,42 are not divisible by 4

Comment: $12$, for a start. (There are more.)

Comment: oh didn't think about that
Thanks! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For a number to be divisible by 4 it has to have its last 2 digits divisible by 4 so, in this case it could be (00,04,12,20,24,32,40,44,52)
In the 5 digit number,
first place can have 5 numbers(except 0)
and the 2nd and 3rd place can have 6
and the last 2 together has 9 possibilities so,

5 * 6 * 6 * (9)
Total combinations = 1620

Comment: Missing $44$ from your list

Comment: @JMoravitz Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

A number is divisible by 4 if and only if EITHER

1. The tens digit is even and the ones digit is divisible by 4 (e.g. 20, 24, 28); OR
2. The tens digit is odd and the ones digit has remainder 2 mod 4 (e.g. 12, 16, 18).

You can use this to revise your list of the possible last two digits. You should get 9 possibilities using the digits 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 (you only listed 6).

Thus the answer will be, using your reasoning, $5 \cdot 6 \cdot 6 \cdot 9 = \boxed{1620}$.

Comment: Why the silly box around the product?

Comment: @amWhy I just like to box the final answer :P

Comment: Whatever turns you on. :P